# How to solve weird bug when launching Google Chrome?

Tags: linux-mint, chrome, cinnamon

I just reinstalled my Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon, because I wanted to clear up any potential clutter in my system. When I am now using Chrome, whenever I launch Chrome, my GUI "shakes" strangely. Some positions of my Desktop shift to others for just a split second, and then Chrome launches and it's all back to normal. This was not present in my Linux Mint before, and it's alarming me. I am not sure if I may need to reinstall again. How can I solve this bug? When I launch chrome from the terminal, I get these errors, but I do not know if they correlate to this:

```
[7673:7673:0205/223143:ERROR:logging.h(808)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetManagedObjects" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" doesn't exist

[7673:7673:0205/223143:ERROR:logging.h(808)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager.GetManagedObjects: object_path= /: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "GetManagedObjects" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" doesn't exist
```

Might this be causing this?

On a side note, I have it in Cinnamon to use a Fade effect when mapping windows. This works on all applications BUT Chrome (and I remember this being consistent with my Linux Mint prior to the reinstallation). Why is this happening?

Comment: I don't know why, Chrome has done this in Mint Cinnamon for as long as I can remember, doesn't hurt anything, but to fix a different issue I switched from google-chrome-stable to google-chrome-beta, and the issue has gone away

Comment: This has been a consistent issue?

Comment: For me, this would happen every single time I would start Chrome,  it has not occurred since moving from 48-stable to 49-bets though